# mkdir says folder exists even though it doesn't show with ls -a

Tags: arch-linux, ls, cifs, mkdir

Arch linux.

I have a CIFS mount from my NAS that was mounted with full permissions

```
# line from my fstab
//IP_ADDRESS/path/to/dir    /path/to/local/dir    cifs    uid=my_user,gid=my_group,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,credentials=path/to/my/creds    0    0
```

and am trying to create a directory, however this fails

```
mkdir path/to/local/dir/subdir
mkdir: cannot create directory '/path/to/local/dir/subdir': File exists
```

However as far as I can tell it *doesn't* exist:

```
ls -la path/to/local/dir
drwxrwxrwx me me 0 date .
drwxrwxrwx me me 0 date ..
```

And looking at the files on my NAS that subdirectory does not exist on the remote. I'm stumped. And I can search for this, it just turns up a bunch of results where people didn't understand what dotfiles are.

What gives?

## Edit

Since I got some pushback on the particulars (fair enough), here are the **exact** commands and output. The `/mnt/nas/SteamLibrary` folder is the local mount point for the folder on the NAS.

```
[I] ⋊> ~ ls -la /mnt/nas/SteamLibrary/steamapps/downloading             
17:19:56ls: cannot access '/mnt/nas/SteamLibrary/steamapps/downloading': No such file or directory
[I] ⋊> ~ mkdir /mnt/nas/SteamLibrary/steamapps/downloading              
17:20:33mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/nas/SteamLibrary/steamapps/downloading’: File exists
[I] ⋊> ~ ls -la /mnt/nas/SteamLibrary/steamapps/                        
17:20:41total 108K
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 18 21:30 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 19 13:49 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 17 16:05 common
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 17 16:04 compatdata
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 17 16:03 shadercache
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Apr 17 16:05 temp
drwxrwxrwx 2 jsmith jsmith    0 Aug 10  2020 workshop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.2K Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_102500.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  686 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_107300.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  694 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_107310.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  498 Apr 19 13:50 appmanifest_1391110.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  483 Apr 19 13:50 appmanifest_1493710.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  745 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_207320.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  863 Feb 27 16:41 appmanifest_219780.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  691 Apr 17 16:03 appmanifest_22320.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  837 Apr 19 13:50 appmanifest_22330.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  516 Feb 27 16:59 appmanifest_256460.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.2K Feb 27 16:59 appmanifest_292030.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  825 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_312540.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.1K Apr 17 16:03 appmanifest_340170.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.1K Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_351970.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  894 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_367500.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  773 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_372360.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.5K Feb 27 16:37 appmanifest_379720.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  599 Apr 17 16:20 appmanifest_391540.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  665 Apr 19 13:49 appmanifest_406110.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  685 Feb 27 16:59 appmanifest_418340.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  794 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_429660.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  985 Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_489830.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  612 Feb 27 16:59 appmanifest_506510.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  667 Feb 27 16:41 appmanifest_522530.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  708 Feb 27 16:41 appmanifest_525240.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith  891 Apr 17 16:03 appmanifest_538680.acf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jsmith jsmith 1.1K Feb 27 16:40 appmanifest_72850.acf
```

Comment: Sorry, ls -laR path/to/local/dir ? R for recursive

Comment: @nissimabehcera it outputs tons of stuff. There are subdirectories in that directory (I omitted them for brevity) but not the one I'm trying to create.

Comment: Can you explain why "blah" appears in the error message? It doesn't appear in either your `fstab` nor in your command input.

Comment: @JimL. I just shorted it instead of typing out /path/to/local/dir/subdir, I'll edit it to be less lazy sorry

Comment: Thanks, accuracy matters.  Use copy-and-paste to ensure that we're seeing the exact commands and error messages that you're seeing. Please edit the question to include the output of `stat /path/to/local/dir/subdir`. Something looks fishy with the file sizes being 0.  Even an empty directory should occupy more than 0 blocks.

Comment: @roaima updated with the exact commands/output

Comment: @JimL. added exact commands and output. I'm guessing 0 because it's a cifs mount? IDK. Filesystems and storage are not my area of expertise.

Comment: Ok that's strange. Very strange. You haven't got a `veto files` entry in your server's `smb.conf`?

Comment: @roaima I don't think so? It's a synology and I configured it through the DSM gui. I'm sshing into it right now

Comment: You said you didn't see a `subdir` directory on your NAS. Did this include checking that there's no _file_ called `subdir`?

Comment: @roaima Ok I figured it out. So there was a symlink in that directory with that name. Didn't show in ls on the arch client. Didn't show in the File Station GUI in synology DSM. But when I ssh'd into the synology and checked ls -l there it was. Why it didn't show in the gui or on the client with the cifs mount i have no idea, but I guess I now know better than to trust DSM next time. Sorry everybody, wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -la /path/to/dir` lists the (empty except for the required `.` and `..` entries) *contents* of `dir`.

Use the `-d` option to see the directory itself, e.g.

```
ls -ld /path/to/dir
```

Read `man ls` there are a host of options. Read `man stat` before committing the error of "parsing `ls`" in a script.

Comment: Thanks, but does not resolve my issue. I've updated the question.

Comment: Did you try `ls -ld`? How does my answer "not resolve" your problem?

Comment: I did try it. Did not show the problematic subdirectory. See my comment on the question for what the problem turned out to be.